# JSON to JSON transformation on keys using Jolt

Tags: java, json, apache-camel, transformation, jolt

Jolt newbie here! I would like to transform a JSON input from this template:

```
[
  {
    "canalId": "",
    "startDate": "",
    "typeCanal": "",
    "origin": "",
    "principal": false,
    "ligne1": "",
    "ligne2": "",
    "ligne4": "",
    "ligne6": ""
  },
  {
    ...
  }
]
```

to the same template, only with some keys changing names:

```
[
  {
    "id_canal": "",
    "startDate": "",
    "media": "",
    "origin": "",
    "principal": false,
    "adrL1": "",
    "adrL2": "",
    "adrL3": "",
    "adrL4": ""
  },
  {
    ...
  }
]
```

So far, I managed to either use this spec:

```
[
    {
      "operation": "shift",
      "spec": {
        "*": {
          "canalId": "&1.id_canal",
          "typeCanal": "&1.media",
          //More if needed
          "*": "&1.&"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
```

But it returns me some indexes that I don't need, plus I would like to keep the fact that it is a Json Array, aka the square brackets.

Or this one but it requires a split on the incoming JSON to deal only with parts of it:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "canalId": "id_canal",
      "typeCanal": "media",
      // More if needed
      "*": "&"
    }
  }
]
```

But in that case, I would like it to become a JSON array and not just a JSON object.

I am using all of this in a Camel route as it is the requirement, is there any Spec I could use that would do the trick? Or maybe another idea based on Camel itself?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Useful tool to test jolt https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#inception

Answer (score 0):

Adding an extra shift following yours would do the trick:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "canalId": "&1.id_canal",
        "typeCanal": "&1.media",
        //More if needed
        "*": "&1.&"
      }
    }
    },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "[&1].&"
      }
    }
    }
  ]
```